# ddeboer/data-import add many to one assotiation to workflow

Tags: symfony, csv

I have many to one assotiation

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Inf\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="produkty")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userproduktu_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $userproduktu;
```

I would like to add my user for every product from csv and implement workflow class

I have my user admin from query

```
$user_admin = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

I've done this but without workflow

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$doctrineWriter = new DoctrineWriter($em,  'InfAccountBundle:Produkt');

$doctrineWriter->disableTruncate();
$doctrineWriter->prepare();

foreach($csvReader as $row) {

    $doctrineWriter->writeItem(array(
        'cenaProduktu'=>$row['cenaProduktu'],
        'vat'=>$row['vat'],
        'userproduktu'=>$user_admin
    ));                     
 }

 $doctrineWriter->finish();
```

How could achieve that?